# Convert array of arrays to jSON and print out with php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have that from a select query:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [id_user] => 1 [id_category] => 1 [name] => Bambas futbol sala [description] => Bambas de futbol sala marca nike, color rojo y negro. Pie 43. [localization] => Barcelona [min_bid] => 25 [expiration] => 300 [terms] => - [highlights] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [id_user] => 1 [id_category] => 6 [name] => Bateria electronica Roland td4 [description] => Vendo bateria electronida roland td4 kv versi�n 2009 por falta de tiempo. [localization] => Madrid [min_bid] => 600 [expiration] => 200 [terms] => - [highlights] => 0 ) )
```

And i want to parse it to a json like this one(with all the fields i got in array)

```
"infos":[ [ { "id_user":"1", "id_category":"1", "name":"Bambas futbol sala", "description":"..." }, { "id_user":"2", "id_category":"3", "name":"Bambas futbol sala", "description":"..." } ] ],
```

How can i do that and print it with php? thanks

Comment: have you tried json_encode et json_decode ?

Comment: i tried, but not works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json_encode` and `json_decode`

Comment: yeah i tried that but this isn't works..

Comment: I have this code and always returs this to me:

 $statement->execute();
 $rawdata = array(); //creamos un array

 while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   $rawdata[] = $row;
 
 }
 print_r($rawdata);
 echo "<br> json encode below : <br>";
 echo json_encode($rawdata , JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);